# Replace won't work on string when fetched, but will when hardcoded

Tags: javascript, replace, react-native

I'm trying to format a phone number using a function which turns "8888888888" into "(888) 888-8888" :

```
function phoneFormat(phone) {

  console.log(phone);

  phone = phone.replace(/[^0-9]/g, '');
  phone = phone.replace(/(\d{3})(\d{3})(\d{4})/, "($1) $2-$3");

  console.log(phone);   

  return phone;
}
```

It works when my json is hardcoded, however when it's fetched from the server, nothing changes and I get no error.

I tried console logging "typeof", but in both circumstances they come back as strings.

I tried setting state to update after the component mounts like so:

```
componentDidMount (){
  var formatPhone = phoneFormat(this.props.profile.phone)
  this.setState({phone: formatPhone})
},
```

and also tried just calling the function inline.

Fetch function:

```
fetchProfile() {

    fetch(PROFILE_API) 
        .then((response) => {
            return response.json();
        })
        .then((json) => {

            console.log(JSON.stringify(json))

            this.setState({
                profile: json
            });

        })
        .catch((error) => {

            this.setState({
                loading: 3
            });
        });


},
```

Then I'm passing the state as props the Component View.

Comment: Can you show the server call and success function?

Comment: What does the JSON you get back from the server look like?

Comment: It's worth checking with a breakpoint or even a simple console.log that your code actually reaches that method call. I'd expect that if you get no error this means the code's not even executed.

Comment: The code is executed. I've added console logs to the function for "phone" before and after replace. In both circumstances phone starts the same. The second log shows no change for the fetched version, and the correct change for the hardcoded version.

Comment: The JSON for the number is "phone" : "8888888888" in quotes.

Comment: Can you just post the `fetch()` promise you're doing and other parts of code? This is probably only a minor glitch you're having.

Comment: @zvona Added, thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was because the number my coworker had in the database was accidentally 9 characters instead of 10. Oops.

Comment: Might want to add error handling, ensuring your read function gets valid data :).

Comment: @KoebmandSTO could you show an example for the function I've got? I'd love to know how to do it in that circumstance.

Comment: Checking for the length In pseudocode: readPhoneNumber(): if (readNumber.length() != 10) raiseError "this is not a phonenumber" else return readNumber. If the read function is also used to read other things you might want to check for this where you use the number, there is also the possibility someone enters a letter etc. might want to check all are digits as well.

Answer (score 1):

I'd do the following:

1. Test it on multiple browsers and possibly different machines to verify that this is not a problem specific to your dev machine.
2. Try to use a different Regex object that Js's string.replace (like http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_obj_regexp.asp) which may provide the desired results.

Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

Since the code is not a completed version, what I can think of is:

Your state "phone" is in fact not directly bind to state "profile", because you set "phone" value in componentDidMount() and it only run once. After componentDidMount() is run, when you call fetch(), setting state "profile" will not trigger the change of state "phone".

If that's the case, my suggestion is to get rid of "phone", and just call phoneFormat(this.state.profile.phone) when you render the layout, as mentioned here (http://facebook.github.io/react/docs/interactivity-and-dynamic-uis.html#what-shouldnt-go-in-state)

Comment: I tried it inline : `<ListText text={phoneFormat(this.props.profile.phone)}/>` but still see no change.